# rabbitmq - worker installed on user side - security considerations

Tags: linux, security, rabbitmq

I've written an API which I would like to be able to write directly on the computers of my users. The API is already able to push onto git repositories, but I would like a more direct way.

For this purpose, I'm writing a rabbitmq worker, that each user will have to install. I plan 1 rabbitmq login per 1 user. Also 1 rabbitmq channel per 1 user. I want to prevent users from writing to each others' rabbitmq queues.

The worker will be launched via `my-worker-ctl start $userName $userKey`.
The user will be able to specify in which folders the worker can work, for example `my-worker-ctl set-project-root $myProjectName $folder`.

Folders in which the project are created are generally owned by the `$USER` or `www-data` group.

I would like to know if there is a way to limit the worker's access to only its installation dir AND the registered directories (`my-worker-ctl set-project-root`). My goal is to prevent the API from writing to the user's other folders, in case the API is breached. By doing this, the API will not be a security hole.

PS: the clients will be only under Linux OS, I won't do a worker version for other OSes.

Comment: What Linux distros and versions?

Comment: Would work at least on a default ubuntu, the user wouldn't have to install specific security packages. For the moment I think to chown the projects to the "my-worker-user" user and the group to "my-user" or "www-data" with "my-user" which is in the www-data group. I don't really like that solution.